# vue, condtional styling for table data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vue function that is currently using nested v-for loops to iterate an object and build a table with rows an cells accordingly. This is working, but I need to figure out how to get a v-if into the most nested part now and look at the `discarded` value in order to set conditional styling.

Basically, for each `td` element, I want to check tests.discarded, and if the number in that field is greater than 0, then color the cell red. Else, color it green

How can I achieve this with the current state of my code? I can't use a v-if in my most nested v-for element

```
namestest: [
  name: "john",
  date: "08/12/21",
  discarded: 4,
  count: 19

]

<tr v-for="(tests, name) in namestest" :key="name">
    <td>@{{ name }}</td>
    //each time i iterate through it, it should check the discarded field and see if greather than 0. If so, then we color the cell red
    <td v-for="date in dates" :key="date">@{{ tests[date] && tests[date].count }}</td>

</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use `v-if` for applying styles conditionally:

```
<td :style="'background: ' + (tests.discarded > 0 ? 'red' : 'green')">@{{ name }}</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can obviously use @slauth solution with **inline expression** inside the style attribute or you can create a method/function.

Whether you're using [Option API](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-api.html) or [Composition API](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html) just define your function which would accept a parameter (discarded).
You can even define multiple methods, one for styling color and the other for conditional rendering the text.

Finally for inline conditions you can always use `<template v-if="something">` anything between template tags will be rendered and template tags will disappear.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
<td>@{{ name }}</td>
<td v-for="date in dates" :style="'background: ' + (tests[date].discarded > 0 ? 'red' : 'blue')" :key="date">@{{ tests[date] && tests[date].count }}</td>
```

And use a conditional inline style. Or, you could put the conditional in the binding of `class`, instead of the `style` attribute. Like

```
<td v-for="date in dates" :class="{ badcell: (tests[date].discarded > 0) }">@{{ tests[date] && tests[date].count }}</td>
```

This way, the class `badcell` will only be applied if `discarded` is greater than 0. And then have a style for the new '`badcell`' class in your CSS or SCSS.

```
td.badcell {
    background-color:red;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```